# Running Common Lisp on Jupyter Notebook Using Docker

Tags: python, docker, docker-compose, jupyter-notebook, common-lisp

I'm interested in running Common Lisp on a Jupyter Notebook environment using Docker. I came across the "common-lisp-jupyter" project by yitzchak, which allows you to run Common Lisp in a Jupyter Notebook. I found instructions on their website (https://yitzchak.github.io/common-lisp-jupyter/install) on how to run it with `repo2docker` and Docker, but I'm having some trouble getting started.

Here are the instructions I found on their website:

#### Using repo2docker

Common-lisp-jupyter can be run as a Docker image managed by repo2docker, which will fetch the current code from GitHub and handle all the details of running the Jupyter Notebook server.

1. First, you need to install repo2docker (sudo may be required):

   ```bash
   pip install jupyter-repo2docker
   ```
2. Once repo2docker is installed, you can build and start the server using the following command. Directions on accessing the server will be displayed once the image is built:

   ```bash
   jupyter-repo2docker --user-id=1000 --user-name=jupyter https://github.com/yitzchak/common-lisp-jupyter
   ```

#### Using a Prebuilt Docker Image

A prebuilt Docker image is available on Docker Hub. You can run it using the following command:

```bash
docker run --network=host -it yitzchak/common-lisp-jupyter jupyter notebook --ip=127.0.0.1
```

#### Building a Local Docker Image

You can also build a local Docker image of common-lisp-jupyter. After cloning the repository, you can use the following command (sudo may be required). This image is based on the `archlinux/base` Docker image:

```bash
docker build --tag=common-lisp-jupyter .
```

After the image is built, you can run a console session with:

```bash
docker run -it common-lisp-jupyter jupyter console --kernel=common-lisp
```

I want to execute these instructions on a Dockerfile and docker-compose file , but I'm encountering some issues. Here are my Dockerfile and Docker Compose files for reference:

**Dockerfile**:

```
# Use the archlinux/base image as the base image
FROM archlinux/base

# Update the package list and install necessary packages
RUN pacman -Syu --noconfirm && \
    pacman -S --noconfirm python python-pip base-devel && \
    pip install jupyter

# Clone the common-lisp-jupyter repository
RUN git clone https://github.com/yitzchak/common-lisp-jupyter && \
    cd common-lisp-jupyter && \
    jupyter-repo2docker --user-id=1000 --user-name=jupyter .

# Expose the Jupyter Notebook port
EXPOSE 8888

# Set the default command to start Jupyter Notebook
CMD ["jupyter", "notebook", "--ip=0.0.0.0"]
```

**Docker Compose (docker-compose.yml)**:

```yaml
version: '3.8'
services:
  common-lisp-jupyter:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    volumes:
      - ./notebooks:/notebooks
    ports:
      - "8888:8888"
    tty: true
    container_name: my-common-lisp-jupyter-container  # Set your desired container name
    image: my-common-lisp-jupyter-image  # Set your desired image name
```

Could someone provide me with a step-by-step guide on how to set up the "common-lisp-jupyter" environment on my local machine using Docker and Docker Compose? Additionally, how can I access the Jupyter Notebook server once it's up and running?

---

Comment: You might want to elaborate on that »… but I'm encountering some issues«.